# Is there way to do split payment over X months with total amount of $$$ in Paypal?

Tags: api, paypal

So I have this problem which is bugging me for past few days.
I'm trying to make a recurring payment for X month of time with Paypal.
Recurring payment itself is working find with Billing Plan and Billing Agreement, but the problem happened in the next stage.

It needs to total up to X amount of money.
So for example, If a customer wants $100 to be paid over 3 months, it will $33.33 monthly and this will total up to $99.99, not $100!
Therefore I was trying to find something that would make me allow to change the last month payment but there was no luck.

Last thing I was going to try was making two separate payment definitions (trial and regular although they both are not trial) and set one as different amount.

Is there any better idea of implementing this feature or anything I couldn't find?

And one more question - what is the difference between trial and regular payment? I know what they mean but what's different in payment wise/program wise? Can I make regular payment definition as trial so I could just have trial payment with different $$$ and then when trial ends, proper regular payment goes through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trial period will work for what you propose, the only disadvantage is that the verbiage might confuse the customer during checkout, since they will see it broken down that way.

> what is the difference between trial and regular payment?

The difference is that one is called 'trial' and one is called 'regular', and one happens before the other. So basically, no other important differences so long as the system accepts the parameters you're setting.

FWIW, most customers would appreciate you rounding down each period and just charging them 33.33. They would think that's fair enough.